# spark fast range lookup on 2 columns

Tags: apache-spark

I have 2 datasets, StudentMarks and Grades.
The Grades table has maximum and minimum marks for each grade.
**Grades Dataset**

```
+-----+--------+--------+
|Grade|Min_Mark|Max_Mark|
+-----+--------+--------+
|    1|       0|       9|
|    2|      10|      19|
|    3|      20|      29|
|    4|      30|      39|
|    5|      40|      49|
|    6|      50|      59|
|    7|      60|      69|
|    8|      70|      79|
|    9|      80|      89|
|   10|      90|     100|
+-----+--------+--------+
```

**StudentMarks Dataset**

```
+---+--------+-----+
| ID|    Name|Marks|
+---+--------+-----+
|  1|   Julia|   88|
|  2|Samantha|   68|
|  3|   Maria|   99|
|  4| Scarlet|   78|
|  5|  Ashley|   63|
|  6|    Jane|   81|
+---+--------+-----+
```

I need to find grade for each student. Expected Result-

```
+---+--------+-----+-----+
| ID|    Name|Marks|Grade|
+---+--------+-----+-----+
|  1|   Julia|   88| 9   |
|  2|Samantha|   68| 7   |
|  3|   Maria|   99| 10  |
|  4| Scarlet|   78| 8   |
|  5|  Ashley|   63| 7   |
|  6|    Jane|   81| 9   |
+---+--------+-----+-----+
```

Is there an efficient way of looking up for number in a range?

Comment: did the answer help you?

Comment: yeah.Taking hint from your answer, I used between function to join the dataframes.


[`code
dfInput.join(dfGrades, dfInput.col("Marks").between(dfGrades.col("Min_Mark"), dfGrades.col("Max_Mark")), "left")
                .drop(functions.col("Min_Mark")).drop(functions.col("Max_Mark")).show();
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `join` with condition as below

```
studentDF.join(markDF,
  studentDF("Marks").lt(markDF("Max_Mark")) && studentDF("Marks").gt(markDF("Min_Mark"))
).drop("Min_Mark", "Max_Mark")
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+-----+-----+
|ID |Name    |Marks|Grade|
+---+--------+-----+-----+
|1  |Julia   |88   |9    |
|2  |Samantha|68   |7    |
|3  |Maria   |99   |10   |
|4  |Scarlet |78   |8    |
|5  |Ashley  |63   |7    |
|6  |Jane    |81   |9    |
+---+--------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you floor the `min_mark` column in the `grades` dataset and JOIN on that:

```
val students2 = student.withColumn("min_mark" , 10 * floor($"marks" / 10))
val df3 = students2.join(grades, col("grades2.min_mark") === col("students.min_mark"))
```

You have edge cases (grade = 100) that you have to deal with. Either do a LEFT join and impute or add a row to your dataframe (with a `union`). Up to you !